# Using multiprocessing to sample several times the same Dataframe and return several sampled Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am very new to multiprocessing but found myself needing to use it to sample several dozens of times the same pandas DataFrame but I'm having some issues.

1) So far I have tried to try to store the results somehow (even though I understand it wouldn't make 100% sense to save them in a list):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool= mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

results = [[]]

for m in [1,2,3,4]:
    uni1 = pool.apply_async(temporary.groupby(['Customer_id','Day','Hour']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1, random_state= m))['Timestamp'], callback= results)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

But when I call back results I get an empty list. I don't know if there is a better way to store them...

2) I have also tried to

```
for m in [1,2,3,4]:
    uni1 = pool.apply_async(temporary.groupby(['Customer_id','Day','Hour']).apply(
    lambda x: x.sample(n=1, random_state= m ))['Timestamp'])
```

But when I can uni1 back it returns me  which I have no idea how to turn into (this case) 4 different Dataframes or something else I can work with

In the end I need to have a pipeline of many different workable DataFrames that I can use to then apply different completion methods and study which is the best by taking the average of all DataFrames' errors. But this of course means that I have to be able to work with the output of this sampling function which I'm just not getting right. If anybody can help I would be most appreciative!

Comment: have you considered using [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)?

Comment: @jeschwar I'm not sure how I would do it because I don't want to take my Dataframe, partition it and then return a Dataframe (this is my very primitive understanding of Dash) I want to take my full Dataframe,  apply a function and then return several Dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to your use case, but would something like the following work? It uses map instead of apply_async.

```py
def helper(variables):
    grouped, m = variables[0], variables[1]
    return grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1, random_state=m))['Timestamp']


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from multiprocessing import Pool

    grouped = df.groupby(['Customer_id', 'Day', 'Hour'])
    p = Pool(4)
    variables = [[grouped, m] for m in [1,2,3,4]]

    results = p.map(helper, variables)

    print results
```

Results here is a list of dataframes.